# How to use an .lnx file on RedHat

Tags: redhat, filesystems

I have an .lnx file that I need to use on the RedHat distribution.
Any idea how to run / install it?

I tryed to make it executable and jut call it but this doesn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is this file and where did you get it from?

Comment: Hi Michael, It is a file that we got from molecular-networks.com. It should basically be an executable file that need to perform some operations. The easier will be to contact the vendor, but I would like to know first what are those lnx files meant to.

Comment: What does the OS think., ie what's the output of `file foo.lnx`?

Comment: corina_annual_Linux2.4_RedHat9_2016_07_10.lnx: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=5598b66dab2a01af6570e5dbad3dcbdca5a9610c, not stripped

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To come back with a working solution here. In order to make this workimg, as mentioned by HBrujn, I had to install

> libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386

with following commands:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is nonsense. dpkg and apt-get are not Red Hat's package managers, these are Debian/Ubuntu package managers.

Comment: @TomAac, you're right, I have an Ubuntu system instlled, the title of the question is wrong and I am not able to update it.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the output  the `file` command:

> corina_annual_Linux2.4_**RedHat9**_2016_07_10.lnx: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, **Intel 80386**, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for **GNU/Linux 2.6.18**, BuildID[sha1]=5598b66dab2a01af6570e5dbad3dcbdca5a9610c, not stripped

The file name seems to indicate it is a version for [**Red Hat Linux 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) which sounds similar but is very much not the same as Red Hat Enterprise Linux ([RHEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux)). Despite the apparently higher release number Red Hat Linux 9 is from 2003 where the current 2015 RHEL release is 7 (and RHEL 5 & 6 are also common).  But this pure conjecture, as filenames don't govern actual functionality.

It is compiled for **Intel 80386** which might be explained as suitable for  [32-bit architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-32) or it might really be intended to run on actual [Intel 80386](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_803860) chipset.

For **GNU/Linux 2.6.18** on the other hand indicates it is intended for Linux kernel 2.6.18 which makes it a build suitable for RHEL 5 and similar.

You may want to use `ldd` to check and see if it depends on external libraries and if those are present, but those requirements are met in theory it should be possible to make it run with `chmod +x  corina_annual_Linux2.4_RedHat9_2016_07_10.lnx`  and `./orina_annual_Linux2.4_RedHat9_2016_07_10.lnx:`

You may have downloaded the wrong binary, or are trying it to run it on the wrong Linux system, however which way you want to call it.